# I want change scrollview rolling speed in react native

Tags: performance, react-native, scrollview

Now I use interval make it come true, but it is very incoherence.
If I can just change the method (`scroll`) speed, it well be nice.

```
this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
    if(!_scroll){
        _this.interval && clearInterval(_this.interval);
    }
    if(totalWide+ScreenWidth >= width ){
        _scroll.scrollWithoutAnimationTo();
        totalWide=0;
        i=0;
    }else{
        _scroll.scrollTo({x:eachWide*i,animate:true});
        totalWide = totalWide + eachWide;
        i= i+1;
    }
},250)
```

Answer (score 11):

use [decelerationRate](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#decelerationrate) property of ScrollView

```
<ScrollView decelerationRate={0.5}>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thinks ,but it is not roll-speed,it is not what I need

Comment: Also note that this property is `iOS` only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reanimated to make it work.

```
const offsetY = useSharedValue(0);


const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps<FlatListProps<unknown>>(() => {
  return {
    contentOffset: {
      x: 0,
      y: offsetY.value,
    },
  };
});

const handleScroll = () => {
  offsetY.value = withTiming(targetIndex * CARD_HEIGHT, {
    duration: YOUR_DURATION_HERE,
  });
}

return <Animated.FlatList animatedProps={animatedProps} ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by having setInterval call a function(in which you define the logic or the pace at which the scroll should move).

```
this.interval= setInterval(this.scrollwithSpeed, 100); // Set the function to this timer
scrollwithSpeed() {
   position = this.state.currentPosition + x; // x decides the speed and 
   currentPosition is set to 0 initially.         
   this.scrollObject.scrollTo(
   { y: position, animated: true }
   );
   this.setState({ currentPosition: position });
}
```

Make sure you call clearInterval(this.interval) after it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to attach to js [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) (from how far I know it is supported in React Native).

Bellow example will scroll linearly from top to bottom. If You need to scoll to different offset just change `distance` variable.

`startingPoint` variable is redundant in scrolling from top to bottom but will stay in example.

```
scroll() {
  if (this.scrollAnimationFrame) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.scrollAnimationFrame);
  }

  this.listRef.scrollToOffset({offset: 0, animated: false}); // remove if You don't start scroll from top

  const duration = this.scrollTime,
        startingPoint = 0, // change if You don't start scroll from top
        distance = Scrolling.LINE_HEIGHT * Scrolling.ITEMS_COUNT;
  let startTimestamp, progress;

  const frameCallback = (timestamp) => {
    if (!startTimestamp) {
      startTimestamp = timestamp;
    }

    progress = timestamp - startTimestamp;

    this.listRef.scrollToOffset({
      offset: distance * (progress / duration) + startingPoint,
      animated: false,
    });

    if (progress < duration) {
      this.scrollAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(frameCallback);
    }
  };

  this.scrollAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(frameCallback);
}
```